# Delete all lines that start with Log.d

Tags: text-processing, command-line, sed

I have an android app and has alot of `Log.d(.....);` type messages that I would simply like to remove.

I just want a command that removes them all (should go through all directories recursively)

One challenge however is that some `Log.d` commands go to the next line, and so some are like this:

`Log.d("I can be easily deleted", "");`

Others are like this

```
Log.d("I span a new line, "hel" 
+ "lo");
```

Also it is not necessary that the spacing is all the same, one `Log.d` would be 30 characters from the start of the line, the other could be 14, etc.

I guess something that could be useful is that they all start with `Log.d`, and end with `);`

**This should just be run on all .java files (*.java)**

What is the command to do this? Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Basic script

I've used perl because it's simpler to match over multiple lines (unlike, say, sed). The basic script is as follows.

```
perl -0777 -pe 's/^Log\.d\(.*?(\n.*?)*?\);\n//gm' input
```

#### Explanation

- `perl -0777 -pe`: invoke perl using `-0777` to slurp the entire file, i.e. allowing multi-line processing.
- `'s/foo/bar/gm'`: replace `foo` with `bar`, even if there are multiple matches (`g`); this is a multiline expression (`m`).
- `^Log\.d\(.*?(\n.*?)*?\);\n`: look for lines starting with `Log.d(`; this expression needs to be escaped (`^Log\.d\(`). There may be more characters after this (`.*?`), possibly a newline with more characters (`(\n.*?)`), and possibly multiple iterations of this last expression (`*?`). After this, look for a closing `);` followed by a newline (escaped as `\);\n`). All of these wildcards are non-greedy (`*?` not `*`). Hence, they will attempt to match the minimum number of characters possible, instead of deleting from the first `^Log\.d\(` to the final `\);\n` of the entire file.

#### Test

`input.txt`:

```
Keep me A
Log.d("I can be easily deleted", "");
Keep me B
Keep me C
Log.d("I span a new line, "hel" 
+ "lo");
Keep me D
```

Run script:

```
$ perl -0777 -pe 's/^Log\.d\(.*?(\n.*?)*?\);\n//gm' input.txt
Keep me A
Keep me B
Keep me C
Keep me D
```

## Iterate over multiple files

After testing the script as above, apply it to multiple files. Use perl's "in-place" option (`-i`) to modify the original files. *Make a backup of the directory first.* If the files are all directly in the same directory, you can just send multiple arguments to the script using shell wildcards.

```
perl -i -0777 -pe 's/^Log\.d\(.*?(\n.*?)*?\);\n//gm' *.java
```

However, given you may have nested directories (and I don't know which shell you are using), you can use `find` here.

```
find /path/to/dir -name '*.java' -execdir perl -i -0777 -pe 's/^Log\.d\(.*?(\n.*?)*?\);\n//gm' {} \;
```

#### Explanation

- `find /path/to/dir`: look in `/path/to/dir`.
- `-name '*.java'`: only find files matching this expression.
- `-execdir perl -i -0777 -pe 's/^Log\.d\(.*?(\n.*?)*?\);\n//gm' {} \;`: run the script above in-place (`-i`) on the matching file `{}`.

Look at `man find` for more information on this format.

## sed version benchmarking

As [don_crissti](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/22142/don-crissti) suggests in the [comments](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/408393/delete-all-lines-that-start-with-log-d/408449#comment731954_408449), there is a sed command that will do this as well.

```
sed -e '/Log/{' -e ': do' -e '/);/d;N' -e 'b do' -e '}' input.txt
```

I tested both commands using the following file as input.

```
Keep me A
Log.d("I can be easily deleted", "");
Keep me B
Keep me C
Log.d("I span a new line, "hel" 
+ "lo");
Keep me D
Log.d("I span a new line, "hel" 
+ "lo" +
+ "there");
Keep me E
```

I did some benchmarking comparing commands. The `perl` version is marginally faster for this file on my system.

```
$ time (for i in {1..1000}; do perl -0777 -pe 's/^Log\.d\(.*?(\n.*?)*?\);\n//gm' input.txt > /dev/null; done)

================
CPU 101%
user    1.484
system  3.372
total   4.793
$ time (for i in {1..1000}; do sed -e '/Log/{' -e ': do' -e '/);/d;N' -e 'b do' -e '}' input.txt > /dev/null; done)

================
CPU 101%
user    2.647
system  2.847
total   5.429
```

I also created another test file that was 1000 repeats of the `input.txt` above. In this case, the sed version was faster.

```
$ time (for i in {1..100}; do perl -0777 -pe 's/^Log\.d\(.*?(\n.*?)*?\);\n//gm' input1000 > /dev/null; done)

================
CPU 100%
user    1.132
system  0.409
total   1.535
$ time (for i in {1..100}; do sed -e '/Log/{' -e ': do' -e '/);/d;N' -e 'b do' -e '}' input1000 > /dev/null; done)

================
CPU 100%
user    0.560
system  0.298
total   0.853
```

Comment: For the record,  `sed` can do it too and it's much shorter (probably faster too): `sed -e '/Log/{/);/!N;d;' -e '}' infile`. That's for messages that may span over two lines. For three or more lines use a loop so as to repeat the `N` as many times as needed : `sed -e '/Log/{' -e ': do' -e '/);/d;N' -e 'b do' -e '}' infile`

Comment: @don_crissti I get confused using `sed` to do multiline stuff. FWIW I benchmarked both in my edited answer.

Comment: With large files (eg. > 100 GB), I got a `Out of memory!` warning. My solution was to open the file with `vim` and use `:g/^Log\.d.*/d` to delete these lines.